# QDevelop problem debugging location pointer disappears

Tags: c, linux, debugging, ide, ubuntu

I am having a problem with QDevelop version 0.27. When I debug the location pointer jumps around without the IDE following it and showing me where it went. I have to manually click through the source file tabs to find where it went sometimes scrolling up and down through the code to find where it is. Once I get to one point I can no longer find where it sent. At one point in debugging the location pointer jumps to a location and there is a split in the IDE windowed area and I see the pointer but it's like two different files are merging graphically. Very weird issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh well mysteriously the issue just up and disappeared without me doing a single thing.